# How to share a file between two PC on two different VPNs

Tags: vpn, tunnel

I need to copy files from one computer to another, but they are not on the same subnetwork. I need to use two different VPN connections to access the two computers. Can I transfer the files between them without using a third-party servers like Dropbox, and without downloading files on my PC, disconnecting from the first VPN, connecting to the second VPN, and uploading files on the target computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is using this marvellous piece of software: https://github.com/magic-wormhole/magic-wormhole